successful_payment python aiogram 3.x
Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что есть 3 функции:
async def buy_process(web_app_message):
    if web_app_message.web_app_data is not None:
        await bot.send_invoice(web_app_message.chat.id,
                               title='Сведение',
                               description='Сделаем в течение 3ёх дней',
                               provider_token='381764678:TEST:82468',
                               currency='rub',
                               need_email=True,
                               prices=PRICE.get(f'{web_app_message.web_app_data.data}'),
                               start_parameter='example',
                               payload='some_invoice',
                               is_flexible=False,
                               request_timeout=15
                               )


async def pre_checkout_process(pre_checkout_query: PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)
    print(pre_checkout_query)

    # Открываем текстовый файл для записи (режим 'a' - добавление)
    with open('email_data.txt', 'a') as file:
        # Записываем информацию
        file.write(
            f"Email: {pre_checkout_query.order_info.email}, Username: {pre_checkout_query.from_user.username}, Total Amount: {pre_checkout_query.total_amount}\n")


async def successful_payment_handler(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("thx man")

И функция successful_payment_handler после того, как пройдёт оплата не вызывается. Хотя в переписке с ботом появляется чек. Всё остальное работает.
зарегана функция таким образом router.message.register(successful_payment_handler,  F.successful_payment)
